# Will becoming a vampire help me survive?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

I'm playing in a campaign in which I have the opportunity to become a vampire, and perhaps limit some of the downsides of it.  I am a level 7 Chaotic Good Alchemist that has been offered 3 castings of Wish in exchange for my character's soul and servitude in Hell, as well as my entire lineage.

What makes this unique is that in this current campaign, it's been going so long that we decided that if we die, we're out until the next campaign.  I sincerely wish to keep playing, so here's my question:

I love the vampire template, and the other stuff that comes with it, but overall, **does becoming a vampire help me survive or hinder my survival?**

It's worth noting that for large sections of the campaign that each player can be run at separate times from the other players.  If I became only active at night, other players would simply play on another night until we're brought back together.

(As asked by @dark wanderer, here's a condensed version of the campaign setting, to give a better understanding of what being a vampire will mean).

Currently, we are on an island that is a sovereign territory of Cheliax.  Cheliax has just fallen, the God-Emperor assassinated, and the son of the rightful successor has imprisoned his father and usurped the throne.

- His specialist legion of 16 elite soldiers, the Order of the Crimson
  Chalice, are mostly human but with a few devils in there.
- Lady Erin, one of the most powerful, is a devil with the ability to
  grant 3 wishes in exchange for one's soul and his lineage's soul.

  My character, though chaotic good, wishes to take the offer, because he is an elf and his wife (also an alchemist)is a human.  He cannot imagine a life without her, so he seeks to make them both immortal.  In doing so, he uses one wish to be a vampire, and the other to make her a vampire.  I'm not sure what the last will be.

  Half of the party will support this, the other half (both paladins) will not.  They probably won't outright attack me as long as I don't do anything explicitly wrong.

  We are using the main books, no 3rd party, and no companions or addendums.  I.E. Race Guide, Advanced Players, Advanced Class, etc.  With the notable exceptions of not allowing Occult Adventures, Pathfinder Unchained, or the use of Advanced Race Guide for anything other than traits and feats regarding the core races.

  My DM will allow me to become Chaotic Neutral or something not evil, because I'm using Wish to attain the vampire status.

Comment: Is there anything (groups, unusual supernatural effects, whatever) in the campaign that would specifically target vampires or undead to try to destroy them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad - it's dependent on too many campaign-, DM-, and player- specific details that we don't have, and you might not even be able to supply us with.

Comment: @TuggyNE There is a paladin of Shelyn in our party, but since my character isn't evil and won't be (story reasons) there's nothing in specific sent to destroy me.

Comment: Regarding Miniman's closure: while you *may* not be able to give us the info we need for this to be a good question, you also *may* be able to.  Whether it's worth trying is up to you.  "Is X single change good or bad for this specific character's long-term survival in this specific campaign" is usually a fine question for our site.  You might want to consider tagging the question 'optimization' and including your character sheet (as a link or at the bottom of the question body).  You also might want to give us at least an overview of the campaign setting.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I've made edits.

Comment: Is it just me or am I seeing a pattern of people downvoting answers to whatever's been put on hold? Especially without feedback

Comment: @Teco I'm not the downvoter but we do generally discourage (in the form of downvotes) people from answering questions that should be (or are very likely to be) put on hold because it can stop the querent from ever clarifying their question since they've "got an answer".

Comment: Doesn't becoming a vampire imply you die first?

Comment: This question is unbounded in time.  Since you make the deal to eventually serve the on an evil plane after you are dead, how long in game time are you trying to stay alive before you have to pay the bill for the three wishes?  While this may be beyond the scope of the question, perhaps, does  your "lineage" only mean children of you and the vampire's wife, or all vampires created by the both or either of you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vampire Template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire)

Yes, it will definitely help in general cases like social interactions, you get bonuses to all your stats except constitution, bluff bonuses, domination, but you'll have to be careful around divine casters, especially if your party doesn't know you're undead and the cleric casts cure moderate wounds on you. Also, you'll be unable to be near mirrors, garlic, holy symbols, and other miscellaneous anti vampire objects. It is extremely important to not be in a place where people can notice you have no shadow, too, but you can probably bluff yourself out of that if needed.

As a chaotic good alchemist, however, it's important to note that alchemists tend to have a lot of free constitution bonuses and not many charisma bonuses, and HP is defined by charisma for vampires. Also, if you plan on traveling a lot, you'll die instantly at 0 hit points rather than take more damage equal to your constitution, but you'll be able to transport back to your coffin if you're close enough to be resurrected. Finally, your alignment becomes evil.

It's also much better to take other templates if you don't plan on brutally murdering several people or a high levelled partner for some vampire bodyguards.

If you can, ask for [the Eternal template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/eternal-cr-2) instead. Don't be surprised if you leave with a book shaped bump on your head. It is, however, third party and it requires you to stop gaining HD and class levels

TLDR; High charisma low constitution characters make <strike>good</strike> evil vampires. High constitution but low charisma characters make average vampires. Live in your basement, don't travel too far without coffin removalists, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Is this a frame challenge?  By that I mean are you suggesting that asking  the DM for permission to use The Eternal as a character template makes for "better survival" and is thus a better answered for the stated problem to solve, which is "if you die you are out of the campaign." (FWIW, that template strikes me as something no DM will allow to a player, based on the description at your provided link).

Comment: The Eternal template comes with the following caveat: "The eternal creature never gains any levels or Hit Dice," which (should this question be reopened) you may wish to point out in your answer as a caveat, as well as the fact that the template comes from a third-party publisher.